# MongoDB Charts Error while testing connection

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to deploy mongo charts on containers. While testing i get below error

I tried serching web .. but did not get right fix

docker run --rm quay.io/mongodb/charts:19.06.1 charts-cli test-connection mongodb://unsername:password@mon009.abc.com:7041,mon001.abc.com:7041/pub_mongo?replicaSet=mongo7041

i get below error .. any clue??

Unable to connect to MongoDB using the specified URI.

The following error was returned while attempting to connect:

MongoParseError: Incomplete key value pair for option

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro the problem with the supplied URI. The only thing I can think of is that the redacted password may contain a special character such as ? which is preventing the URI from being parsed. Make sure you are URL-encoding any special characters in the password.